# plpgsql calling one function in another function with multiple values

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Fetch multiple values from one select statement and pass those values individual into another function. we need results in a table format.

select statement results are

```
123,abc,45c
```

and pass those values into another sql query and result should be

```
clo1    col2(Int)   Col3(Int)   Col4 (Char)
123 45  98  A
123 58  97  B
123 72  58  C
abc 22  64  A
abc 58  87  B
abc 89  59  C
45c 78  52  A
45c 98  30  B
45c 100 54  C
```

Comment: `where (col2, col3, col4) in ( select a,b,c, ...)`

Comment: plpgsql function? SQL statement? Your question is a mess. Please show some effort to present a clear question. Provide table definition, the query you have now (even if it's not working) and your Postgres version to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call on function on the select statement, it will pass all results into function 1 by 1, like

```
SELECT func(123,abc,45c) FROM tableX
```

For returning result as table format, set the return type of function as table according to your output design , like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(a int,b bigint, c int)
RETURNS TABLE(x int, y int) AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Your function's internal processing
  RETURN QUERY SELECT x, y FROM Tablex WHERE x = a;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`lateral`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) to be able to refer to the select result:

```
select f.*
from
    (
        select a, b, c
        from t
        where x = 1
    ) s
    cross join lateral
    my_function(a, b, c) f
```